# Get properties from Array in JSON in VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, api

I need result from this JSON:

```json
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjBGOTkyNkZFQTUyOTgxRjZDMjBENUMzNUQ0NjUxMzAzQ0QzQzBFMzIiLCJ0eXAiOiJhdCtqd  3QiLCJ4NXQiOiJENWttX3FVcGdmYkNEVncxMUdVVEE4MDhEakkifQ.eyJuYmYiOjE2MjA3NzEyNDEsImV4cCI6MTYyMDc3NDg0MSwiaXNzIjoiaH    R0cHM6Ly9pZC5wcmVwcm9kLmV0YS5nb3YuZWciLCJhdWQiOiJJbnZvaWNpbmdBUEkiLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJlZWQ4YWY2MS01ZjRmLTQxM2MtYWZlN S1jYjg0YjBiOTlhOGMiLCJJbnRlcm1lZElkIjoiMCIsIkludGVybWVkUklOIjoiIiwiSW50ZXJtZWRFbmZvcmNlZCI6IjIiLCJuYW1lIjoiMjAyNDY5NzM  1OmVlZDhhZjYxLTVmNGYtNDEzYy1hZmU1LWNiODRiMGI5OWE4YyIsInNpZCI6IjJiYzcxYTlhLWQ1MzAtMzc1ZC0zNjMzLTUwN2E3OWFjY2Y1ZiIsInByZW ZlcnJlZF91c2VybmFtZSI6IkVSUCIsIlRheElkIjoiNTE4MDEiLCJUYXhSaW4iOiIyMDI0Njk3MzUiLCJQcm9mSWQiOiI1NDgxNCIsIklzVGF4QWRtaW4iO
    iIwIiwiSXNTeXN0ZW0iOiIxIiwiTmF0SWQiOiIiLCJzY29wZSI6WyJJbnZvaWNpbmdBUEkiXX0.IIxTKWdH0cUInlzrIMON95f7S6vW-CBfRoK8ZxOI6mqp
    DbRLBaZQZyNoYl4A6JYQR6FJY4YVIFUsAbkKEKwwB1MaOpMMWmkyySfUmgvBMvEo6EZnT-oewnSd2EPF_bIK7-HTGug7Rjdy__wTpBr-6PH5kzR79xXzNh_s
    R7TIPcvjJ-nx7eNZREdk4J7M3X8Mfjzww2RkbizN5zXNpmc5OHh_VLtlkA-4zQrs102HA9VFTxLEIdXhrpBqEBmy9dt-onZpuiKbkioV5iH2uwAkQbDvnM9h
    p7EJscL0y0xFjfwbAUxQx3ohcXtA31fwyYazKQVKHCtNm9SPgSsQ-rKevQ",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "scope": "Accecc DB"
}
```

I used:

```vb
    Dim Mytoken As JObject = JObject.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
    TextBox2.Text = Mytoken.SelectToken("access_token").ToString
```

Now I Need to get the `uuid`, `longId`, `internalId`, and `hashKey` from the `acceptedDocuments` like this:

```json
{
    "submissionId": "5hfhfgy5653uytyu45fg457",
    "acceptedDocuments": [
                           {
                             "uuid": "hlg5fdg7ggnjgh",
                             "longId": "jgjhk78jm,jhk54567ujnfgh7fggh",
                             "internalId": "477",
                             "hashKey": "dfgdfhdyjfghryjghjj"
                            }
                          ],
    "rejectedDocuments": []
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Newtonsoft.Json and deserialize the response into an object:

```vb
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class Submission
        Public submissionId As String
        Public acceptedDocuments As List(Of AcceptedDocuments)
        Public rejectedDocuements As String 'not sure of the type of this property
End Class

Public Class AcceptedDocuments
        Public uuid As String
        Public longId As String
        Public internalId As Integer
        Public hashKey As String
End Class

Public Function DeserilizeJson(ByRef json As String) As Submission
        Dim doc As Submission = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Submission)(json)
        Return doc
End Function
```

This should result in a `Submission` class object being created, to which you can reference all of the members of it, including the List of `AcceptedDocuments` (you can iterate over the list as needed).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem

```
 Dim Mytoken As JObject = JObject.Parse(TextBox1.Text)

    TextBox2.Text = "My submissionId IS:     " & Mytoken.SelectToken("submissionId").ToString & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine


    
    Dim arrray As JArray = JArray.Parse(Mytoken.SelectToken("acceptedDocuments").ToString)
    For Each acceptedDocuments In arrray
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text & "My uuid IS:  " & acceptedDocuments.SelectToken("uuid").ToString & Environment.NewLine
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text & "My longId IS:  " & acceptedDocuments.SelectToken("longId").ToString & Environment.NewLine
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text & "My internalId IS:  " & acceptedDocuments.SelectToken("internalId").ToString & Environment.NewLine
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text & "My hashKey IS:  " & acceptedDocuments.SelectToken("hashKey").ToString & Environment.NewLine

    Next
```